# Getting same login page source, when trying to connect to vaadin page using jersey client

Tags: java, rest, jersey, vaadin

I am trying to download files from Vaadin UI on server with jersey client. But instead of login, it is giving me same source code as of Vaadin UI login page. Can someone please suggest better way to do similar thing or suggest where am I going wrong.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        formData.add("***", "***"); //form param
        formData.add("***", "***"); // form param
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("https://URL/").build()); 
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
        System.out.println("Response " + response.getEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve. It looks like you're using a REST client to access a Vaadin web-app, which for me does not make much sense. Can you please emphasise on the subject?

Comment: Thanks Morfic for your comment. Actually, I am not much aware of how to access Vaadin web app. Earlier we have to access jsp pages from where I can see post request and by giving parameters with url I was able to access/download jsp/files. But with Vaadin page, it does show get/post request but didn't show parameters in query. Looks as if everything is based on java script. Kindly suggest which technology to use to download files from Vaadin pages.

Comment: Usually Vaadin apps are regular websites, much like Stackoverflow for example. Most of the app's logic happens on the server side and communication with the browser side is based on AJAX (or websockects). What do you mean by `to download files from Vaadin pages`?  What is exactly your use case, what are you trying to do?

Comment: We access web page(at some url) and from particular location (after few clicks) download data (xml files) from client (to process data in those files). Earlier web pages were in jsp, so through developer tools- we access requests associated with clicks and by giving exact requests and parameters for those request, were able to download files automatically by java code(HttpClient).  Now client has changed its website to Vaadin and its not showing any requests (in developer tool).